# return count() day matches mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table, where id_user=7

TABLE

```
7    2018-11-12
7    2018-11-12
7    2018-11-13
7    2018-11-13
7    2018-11-13
7    2018-11-13
7    2018-11-14
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-15
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
7    2018-11-16
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
 day 12/11/2018 > 2
 day 13/11/2018 > 4 
 day 14/11/2018 > 1
 day 15/11/2018 > 5
 day 16/11/2018 > 7
```

I want to return the times the user appeared by day

I've tried so far...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM posts
WHERE 1
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: you got any error ????

Comment: no, what about DATE(date)?

Comment: I posted an answer, can you please check that ???

Comment: @joe If any of the answers below solve your problem, you should consider marking it as accepted answer. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query :**

```
 SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM posts
    WHERE id_user = 7
    GROUP BY date
```

**Output :**

```
date       | Total
-----------------
2018-11-12 | 2
2018-11-13 | 4
2018-11-14 | 1
2018-11-15 | 5
2018-11-16 | 7
```

**Update :**

If you want to change the date format please use the below code,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d/%m/%Y") As date, COUNT(*) AS Total
        FROM posts
        WHERE id_user = 7
        GROUP BY date
```

**Output :**

```
date       | Total
-----------------
12/11/2018 | 2
13/11/2018 | 4
14/11/2018 | 1
15/11/2018 | 5
16/11/2018 | 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not outputting the date in your query, and you're also not conditioning the results on `id_user`. Try this:

```
SELECT `date`, COUNT(*)
FROM posts
WHERE id_user = 7
GROUP BY `date`
```

Output

```
date        COUNT(*)
2018-11-12  2
2018-11-13  4
2018-11-14  1
2018-11-15  5
2018-11-16  7
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=431e6c820c5708854e988f8069a1d5c6)